# &amp; xhtml URL: fetch parameters

Tags: php, url

This question might have been asked several times, but i didn't find a solution for it.
If I want to have an URL with &  like

```
http://www.mydomain.de?val1=test1&amp;val2=test1
```

how can I fetch these parameters with PHP?

$_GET[]  doesn't work because it expects a plain & as separator. 
Any advice?

Comment: why can't you just use the & seperator?

Comment: If you have `&amp;` in the URL something is wrong. It should only appear in the HTML code so it ends up as a plain `&` in the actual URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `html_entity_decode` to convert `&amp;` to `&` or any similar character

**Via URL**

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = html_entity_decode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
var_dump($_GET);
```

**Simple String**

```
$url = "http://www.mydomain.de?val1=test1&amp;val2=test1";
$url = html_entity_decode(parse_url($url,PHP_URL_QUERY));
parse_str($url,$parts);
var_dump($parts);
```

Output

```
array
  'val1' => string 'test1' (length=5)
  'val2' => string 'test1' (length=5)
```

Comment: Thx, worked for me. It also depends on the browser. Some turn the &amp; directly into &. Dangerous thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.